# Angular Material md-chips not refreshing correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am developing an app that works with a "Widget layout".

The user gets a page which is a Dashboard with different widgets he can interact with, such as a table, graphs etc.

I am adding a **global** *"filter"* using `<md-chips>`, the objective of this is having filters that are *shared* by all the widgets and can be *updated* by all the widgets.

My Filter list uses `<md-chips>`, with read-only and md-removable set to `True`. So filters can only be deleted, or added by interacting with the widgets (so only added programmatically).

One of the feature of this *"module"* is to add a **new filter** on a field when a Graph element *is clicked*.

**Example** :

Here is my Filters list before clicking a Graph element
[image: filters empty]

Now I click on a Graph element which is in a Child controller of my Filter controller, it will `$emit` an event to say to the global controller : **"I want to update the filters ! here is the filter to add"**

And the Filter Controller will get that event and **update** his filters accordingly (`$scope.tags` is the list of filters and the model used in `<md-chips>`)

```
  // CHIPS
  $scope.tags = [];
  $scope.readOnly = true;
  $scope.removable = true;

  // FILTER LISTENER
  $scope.$on('filterChildChanged', function (event, filter) {
    $scope.tags.push(filter);
    console.log($scope.tags);
    console.log("Parent event fired !");
  });
```

At that point I would expect the `<md-chips>`element to refresh, because `$scope.tags` just got a new filter :

```
<md-chips
    ng-model="tags"
    readonly="readOnly"
    md-removable="removable"
    id="filters">
    <md-chip-template>{{$chip.value}}</md-chip-template>    
</md-chips>
```

But instead, nothing happens! and the weird part is, it refreshes when I click on one of the existing chip (I had a "test" chip) !

**TESTS** :
So when I push a test chip on the array before rendering :

```
$scope.tags.push({field: "testField", value: "test"});
```

[image]

And click on a bunch of Graph elements, `$scope.tags` is perfectly updated, BUT the visual stays the same until I select the chip "test", then all the `<md-chips>` appear just like it triggered some *refresh function*.

[image]

Any hint on why the `<md-chips>` element is not refreshed as `$scope.tags` (its model) is updated **BUT** is updated when a chip is selected ?

I tried to trigger `md-on-select` to *force* this behavior to happen every time I add a new filter to `$scope.tags` but I got no luck so far !

Thanks for reading !

**NOTE :** I am using the latest version of Angular MATERIAL (HEAD MASTER) see doc here : https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/ | built from the GitHub repository.

**EDIT** : The problem comes from **$$hashKey** not being added to the objects, they are only added when I click on one of the existing tags, I need to find a way to add this **$$hashKey** attribute when I add a new filter

Answer (score 2):

The problem came from the absence of **$$hashKey** when I added a new filter to my filters model for my **chips** ($scope.tags).

So I just needed to change

```
$scope.tags.push(filter);
```

to

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.tags.push(filter);
});
```

And here is my `console.log` test
[image]

**Good thing I learned** : 
the `<md-chips>` directive only knows it needs to be updated if its `<chip>` objects have a **$$hashKey**

See [this](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) on **scope.$apply**